# Is it possible to setup Hyperledger Fabric network using RedHat Openshift in production?

Tags: openshift, hyperledger-fabric

Keeping in mind that "peer" node creates and starts "chaincode" container (dev-*) using communication path /var/run/docker.sock to the Docker demon, I have some doubts it is doable in production ready RH Openshift cluster.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the only solutions for running HLF components in Openshift clusters are:

a) step into Docker-In-Docker setup - cons: requires privileged containers  in Openshift. It's unacceptable for production ready clusters.

b) run "chaincode" in dev-mode - cons: dev-mode is for development only. It's not suitable for production.

Starting "chaincode" containers outside Openshift cluster and communicate with them using TCP/IP connection is not possible because Openshift cluster uses layer7 reverse proxy for communication with pods.

so the question remains:

Q: Is it possible to setup HLF network using RedHat Openshift in production?

Answer (score 0):

No immediate way around Docker in Docker
○ Security risk remains so evaluate risks before production use
○ setenforce permissive
■ Allows use of docker.sock
■ Make sure you change it on all the nodes
○ oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
■ Privileged mode

Short term Brute force solution
● Look to use Secrets and ConfigMaps to replace host mounts
● Use NFS mounts where needed
○ `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user hostmount-anyuid -z default`
● Replace docker-compose, docker calls with:
○ kubectl , oc, podman,Buildah, kompose
● Convert docker-compose.yaml files with kompose
○ `kompose convert --provider=openshift -f`
■ Then edit and merge files
● Alternate (if fairly simple yaml file)
○ `kompose up --provider==openshift -f`

**Read more** from here: https://www.redhat.com/files/summit/session-assets/2019/T905A4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run HLF in OpenShift, but DinD is required to do it right now on v1.4.4, and thus privileged pods. Properly securing the cluster can negate the risk and many, many organizations are running in production using OpenShift and Kube with privileged pods.

That being said, Fabric v2.0.0 will ship with a new chaincode model that will allow you to run Fabric without DinD. We are planning to release the official v2.0.0 release before the end of the month. If you want to test it out now, v2.0.0-beta is available here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta